# Pass value across pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Using Asp.Net with dynamic Data. The user is on the Diary Page and clicks the hyperlink - Print preview of todays events which loads the TodayesDiaryEntires Page.

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="LoadPreviewOfTodaysEvents" NavigateUrl="~/TodaysDiaryEntries.aspx" Text="Print preview of todays events"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I have a value on the Diary Page: this.DiaryDate, what is the best way to pass it to the TodaysDiaryEntries page when the user clicks on the hyperlink?

Thank you

Comment: How about using Sessions? http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: Or using the query string: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString. This question might also help you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1069641.aspx/1

Comment: so to pass a session would be something like <%
Session("DiaryDate")="this.DiaryDate"
%> where abouts do I put that inside my current asp:hyperlink?

Comment: to use a query string, do i have to change it to a link button and run an onclick or onCommand? then do a query string and pass the sesh?

Comment: @John, I updated my response with another link - that should make it a bit clearer for you.

Comment: I'm confused, you tagged the question with MVC3 but you describe using WebForms controls?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Hyperlink, you cannot use PreviousPage property to get hold of source page. If the TodaysDiaryEntries  is loaded on a iframe or in a new windows, you can use Window.parent javascript property to get hold of the date at client side.

Otherwise you would need to write the javascript funcation which will create the redirection url and embed the date in it as a query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that date using query string by using linkbutton instead of Hyperlink because in linkbutton you can set commandargument using that u can get value of date.
or you can also use session variable to pass value from one page to another page.

Thank you.